# HTML table row background color not as expected with float property

Tags: html, css, html-table

My table has column pairs like Name = Value. For visual clarity, the "td" element that contains the Name is styled as float:right. But this breaks the even/odd background-color CSS rule. I want the td with class DK_name to be **completely** filled with the background-color defined in another CSS rule...

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks In Advance...

CSS:

```
table{font-family:"Lucida Console",Monaco,monospace;font-size:0.85em;border-collapse:collapse;}
td.DK_name {float:right;}
tr.DK_even td{background-color:#DDDDDD;color:black;}
tr.DK_odds td{background-color:#FFFFFF;color:black;}
```

HTML:

```
<table border='0' cellpadding='7' cellspacing='1'>
    <tr class='DK_even'><td class='DK_name'>name_00_blah =</td><td>123.4</td><td class='DK_name'>name_01 =</td><td>123.7</td></tr>
    <tr class='DK_odds'><td class='DK_name'>name_10 =</td><td>123.5</td><td class='DK_name'>name_11_blah_blah =</td><td>123.8</td></tr>
    <tr class='DK_even'><td class='DK_name'>name_20_blah_blah =</td><td>123.6</td><td class='DK_name'>name_21_blah =</td><td>123.9</td></tr>
</table>
```

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bTcMR/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were probably trying to align the text to the right, but `float` isn't the right setting for this.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/bTcMR/1/)

Use this instead:

```
td.DK_name { text-align: right; }
```

---

BTW - You don't need special classes to make the table's rows striped. You can use the CSS [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) pseudo class for this.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) td{background-color:#DDDDDD;color:black;}
tr:nth-child(even) td{background-color:#FFFFFF;color:black;}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/bTcMR/3/)

```
<table border='0' cellpadding='7' cellspacing='1'>
    <tr><td class='DK_name'>name_00_blah =</td><td>123.4</td><td class='DK_name'>name_01 =</td><td>123.7</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='DK_name'>name_10 =</td><td>123.5</td><td class='DK_name'>name_11_blah_blah =</td><td>123.8</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='DK_name'>name_20_blah_blah =</td><td>123.6</td><td class='DK_name'>name_21_blah =</td><td>123.9</td></tr>
</table>
```